# Await and Async callbacks hell

Tags: promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I want to make the UserDataGenerator class works like a traditional SYNC class.

My expectation is that `userData.outputStructure` can give me the data prepared.

```
let userData = new UserDataGenerator(dslContent)
userData.outputStructure
```

`getFieldDescribe(this.inputStructure.tableName, field)` is a ASYNC call which invokes `Axios.get`

Below is my current progress but it's still not waiting for the data ready when I print out the `userData.outputStructure`

export default class UserDataGenerator {
    inputStructure = null;
    outputStructure = null;
    fieldDescribeRecords = [];

```
 constructor(dslContent) {

    this.outputStructure = Object.assign({}, dslContent, initSections)
    process()
}

async process() {
    await this.processSectionList()
    return this.outputStructure
}

async processSectionList() {
    await this.inputStructure.sections.map(section => {
       this.outputStructure.sections.push(this.processSection(section));
    })
}

async processSection(section) {
    let outputSection = {
        name: null,
        fields: []
    }
    let outputFields = await section.fields.map(async(inputField) => {
        return await this._processField(inputField).catch(e => {
            throw new SchemaError(e, this.inputStructure.tableName, inputField)
        })
    })
    outputSection.fields.push(outputFields)
    return outputSection
}

async _processField(field) {
    let resp = await ai
    switch (typeof field) {
        case 'string':
            let normalizedDescribe = getNormalizedFieldDescribe(resp.data)
            return new FieldGenerator(normalizedDescribe, field).outputFieldStructure
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't make something sync if it is async. Your `process` function returns a promise, so something somewhere needs to wait for it before you log `outputStructure`.

Comment: In my case, how could I modify my class as a promise class/function ? Thanks

Comment: You can do `userData.process().then(data => console.log(data))`. There is no way to wait for something inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `await` arrays, which doesn't work as you expect. When dealing with arrays of promises, you still need to use `Promise.all` before you can `await` it - just like you cannot chain `.then` on the array.

So your methods should look like this:

```
async processSectionList() {
    const sections = await Promise.all(this.inputStructure.sections.map(section => 
         this.processSection(section)
    ));
    this.outputStructure.sections.push(...sections);
}

async processSection(section) {
    return {
        name: null,
        fields: [await Promise.all(section.fields.map(inputField =>
            this._processField(inputField).catch(e => {
                throw new SchemaError(e, this.inputStructure.tableName, inputField)
            })
        ))]
    };
}
```